# Cannot SSH from Windows 10 to VirtualBox Debian

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I am trying to establish an SSH connection from a Windows 10 Home host to a Debian guest. I have followed several guides and created a Host-only network. I have enabled I/O APIC and created a static IP on the guest. Nevertheless, I cannot connect using that IP. I also found guides that say to use port forwarding, and while that works, all SSH connections are refused.
This connection will be for Visual Studio remote linux debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putty fails to connect to second VirtualBox VM on Windows 10 Host](https://superuser.com/questions/1394227/putty-fails-to-connect-to-second-virtualbox-vm-on-windows-10-host)

Comment: Are you using a static IP from the same subnet as the host-only adapter on your Windows system?  Not sure why you'd need port forwarding when both should be on the same network.

Comment: I think that's the problem. Different subnets. I didn't know they had to be the same. Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner at this